# Contents in heading, but I don´t want it. What to do?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3cm, top=3cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}\setlength\headheight{40pt} 
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{SRH LOGO.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \line(1,0){300}\\
        [0.25in]
        \huge{\bfseries Master Thesis Proposal} \\
        [2mm]
        \line(1,00){300} \\
        [1.5cm]  
        \textsc{\LARGE Vedhas Pathak} \\
        \textsc{\LARGE Matriculation No.:11012514} \\
        [2cm]
        \textsc{\LARGE{IoT in Foundry Industry: Applications and Implications}} \\ 
        [3cm]
        \textsc{\LARGE Guide: Prof. Eckhard Neumann} \\
        [9cm]       
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
 
\tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{fancy}\setlength\headheight{42pt} 
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{SRH LOGO.jpg}}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please explain in the question what your question is? (3) please make sure your example is complete (here there are stuff missing, so we cannot test the code) and make sure the code does not contain stuff that others do not have access to, heer for example you are loading images we don't have, you can either remove the images if they are not relevant or use `\rule{width}{height}` to get a black box.

Comment: after writing this code, I am getting 'Contents' in header of the document and this is happening just for the Table of Content page. 
rest of the document is fine. 
P.s.: Thanks for the welcome and tip.

Comment: Don't repeat `\pagestyle{fancy}` after `\tableofcontents` and add `thispagestyle{plain}` before.